# SAS: assign serial number based on the group

Tags: sas

I know there are similar questions regarding serial numbers but my case is a little different.
I need to assign serial number based on the group variable. Now, I have my data sorted by the group variable. The following data is just a part of the whole dataset. Basically, I want to create "serial_num" variable that assign unique serial number by the group as shown below.

For example, when group = 1, each has own unique serial number. When group = 2, there are two identical serial numbers. I hope you guys get the pattern by observing the data below.

Thanks in advance.

```
serial_num  group
----------------
1           1
2           1
.           .
.           .
.           .
7           2
7           2
8           2
8           2
.           .
.           .
.           .    
10          3
10          3
10          3
11          3
11          3
11          3
.           .
.           .
.           .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An odd requirement, but here's a solution using plain old data step.

```
data output;
   set input;
   by group;
   if first.group or c = group then do;
      c = 0;
      serial_num + 1;
   end;
   c + 1;

   drop c;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

A rough solution using IML. Mainly to check with you whether it fits the pattern you want then if necessary, I can expand it to enable data set input or make improvement.

Note: y is the generated serial number vector.

```
proc iml;
x={1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4};
y=j(nrow(x),1,.);

y[1,1]=1;
j=1;
 do i=2 to nrow(y);
   if y[i-x[i,1],1]=j then do;
       j=j+1;
       y[i,1]=j;
    end;
  else if x[i,1]^=x[i-1,1] then y[i,1]=y[i-1,1]+1; 
    else y[i,1]=y[i-1,1];
end;
print y;
quit;
```

Comment: To improve efficiency, you can use the UNIQUE-LOC trick or the UNIQUEBY function. For example, see http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/11/07/an-efficient-alternative-to-the-unique-loc-technique/

Comment: Thanks! Well, there is a bit of problem. There are four different groups (1 to 4) and I have 500,000+ observations.

Comment: @statchoi so it this code fits the pattern you want? If yes, then for your concern of efficiency, I can improve it according to Rick's suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have proc iml available at work which is surprising to me. So, I can't verify if the code fits the pattern.